# Pulling data from a files after being matched to a regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, matching

I have two files that contain hashes, one of them looks something like this:

```
user_id,user_bio,user_pass,user_name,user_email,user_banned,user_regdate,user_numposts,user_timezone,user_bio_status,user_lastsession,user_newpassword,user_email_public,user_allowviewonline,user_lasttimereadpost
1,<blank>,a1fba56e72b37d0ba83c2ccer7172ec8eb1fda6d,human,human@place.com,0,1115584099,1,2.0,1,1115647107,<blank>,0,1,1115647107
2,<blank>,b404bac52c91ef1f291ba9c2719aa7d916dc55e5,josh,josh@place.com,0,1115584767,1,2.0,5,1115585298,<blank>,0,1,1115585126
3,<blank>,3a5fb7652e4c4319455769d5462eb2c4ac4cbe79,rich,rich@place.com,0,1167079798,1,2.0,5,1167079798,<blank>,0,1,1167079887
```

The other one, looks something like this:

```
This is a random assortment 3a5fb7652e4c4319455769d5462eb2c4ac4cbe79 of characters in order 3a5fb7652e4c4319455769d5462eb2c4ac4cbe79 to see if I can find a file 3a5fb7652e4c4319455769d5462eb2c4ac4cbe79 full of hashes
```

I'm trying to pull the hashes from these files using a regular expression to match the hash:

```
def hash_file_generator(self):
    def __fix_re_pattern(regex_string, to_add=r""):
        regex_string = list(regex_string)
        regex_string[0] = to_add
        regex_string[-1] = to_add
        return re.compile(''.join(regex_string))

    matched_hashes = set()
    keys = [k for k in bin.verify_hashes.verify.HASH_TYPE_REGEX.iterkeys()]
    with open(self.words) as wordlist:
        for item in wordlist.readlines():
            for s in item.split("\n"):
                for k in keys:
                    k = __fix_re_pattern(k.pattern)
                    print k.pattern
                    if k.findall(s):
                        matched_hashes.add(s)
    return matched_hashes
```

The regular expression that matches these hashes, looks like this: `[a-fA-F0-9]{40}`.

However, when this is run, it pulls everything from the first file and saves it into the set, and in the second file it will work successfully:

First file:

```
set(['1<blank>,a1fba56e72b37d0ba83c2ccer7172ec8eb1fda6d,human,human@place.com,0,1115584099,1,2.0,1,1115647107,<blank>,0,1,1115647107','2,<blank>,b404bac52c91ef1f291ba9c2719aa7d916dc55e5,josh,josh@place.com,0,1115584767,1,2.0,5,1115585298,<blank>,0,1,1115585126','3,<blank>,3a5fb7652e4c4319455769d5462eb2c4ac4cbe79,rich,rich@place.com,0,1167079798,1,2.0,5,1167079798,<blank>,0,1,1167079887'])
```

Second file:

```
set(['3a5fb7652e4c4319455769d5462eb2c4ac4cbe79'])
```

How can I pull just the matched data from the first file using the regex as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/UpQWeh/2), and why is it pulling everything instead of just the matched data?

---

*Edit for comments*

```
def hash_file_generator(self):
    """
      Parse a given file for anything that matches the hashes in the
      hash type regex dict. Possible that this will pull random bytes
      of data from the files.
    """
    def __fix_re_pattern(regex_string, to_add=r""):
        regex_string = list(regex_string)
        regex_string[0] = to_add
        regex_string[-1] = to_add
        return ''.join(regex_string)

    matched_hashes = []
    keys = [k for k in bin.verify_hashes.verify.HASH_TYPE_REGEX.iterkeys()]
    with open(self.words) as hashes:
        for k in keys:
            k = re.compile(__fix_re_pattern(k.pattern))
            matched_hashes = [
                i for line in hashes
                for i in k.findall(line)
            ]
    return matched_hashes
```

Output:
`[]`

Comment: Why do you do `readlines()` then `split('\n')` the results?  They are already lines!

Comment: Since the values are in between commas, just use `res = re.findall(r'\b[a-fA-F0-9]{40}\b', text)`.

Comment: To be honest you could probably use `line.split(",")[2]`

Comment: `matched_hashes.add(s)` - you are adding the whole line (`s`) if there is a match, not the hash that was in the line.

Comment: If they always occur in the same column(s), why are you using RegEx at all? Review [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I can't the files are always different I need a way to split the file so that it can also be split with different format of a file

Comment: @JohnZwinck because that worked for the first file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to pull the hashes, this should work:

```
import re

hash_pattern = re.compile("[a-fA-F0-9]{40}")

with open("hashes.txt", "r") as hashes:
    matched_hashes = [i for line in hashes
                        for i in hash_pattern.findall(line)]

print(matched_hashes)
```

Note that this doesn't match some of what look like hashes because they contain, for example, an `'r'`, but it uses your specified regex.

The way this works is by using `re.findall`, which just return a list of strings representing each match, and using a list comprehension to do this for each line of the file.

When `hashes.txt` is

```
user_id,user_bio,user_pass,user_name,user_email,user_banned,user_regdate,user_numposts,user_timezone,user_bio_status,user_lastsession,user_newpassword,user_email_public,user_allowviewonline,user_lasttimereadpost
1,<blank>,a1fba56e72b37d0ba83c2ccer7172ec8eb1fda6d,human,human@place.com,0,1115584099,1,2.0,1,1115647107,<blank>,0,1,1115647107
2,<blank>,b404bac52c91ef1f291ba9c2719aa7d916dc55e5,josh,josh@place.com,0,1115584767,1,2.0,5,1115585298,<blank>,0,1,1115585126
3,<blank>,3a5fb7652e4c4319455769d5462eb2c4ac4cbe79,rich,rich@place.com,0,1167079798,1,2.0,5,1167079798,<blank>,0,1,1167079887
```

this has the output

```
['b404bac52c91ef1f291ba9c2719aa7d916dc55e5', '3a5fb7652e4c4319455769d5462eb2c4ac4cbe79']
```

Having looked at your code as it stands, I can tell you one thing: `__fix_re_pattern` probably isn't doing what you want it to. It currently removes the first and last character of any regex you pass it, which will ironically and horribly mangle the regex.

```
def __fix_re_pattern(regex_string, to_add=r""):
    regex_string = list(regex_string)
    regex_string[0] = to_add
    regex_string[-1] = to_add
    return ''.join(regex_string)

print(__fix_re_pattern("[a-fA-F0-9]{40}"))
```

will output

```
a-fA-F0-9]{40
```

I'm still missing a lot of context in your code, and it's not quite modular enough to do without. I can't meaningfully reconstruct your code to reproduce any problems, leaving me to troubleshoot by eye. Presumably this is an instance method of an object which has the `words`, which for some reason contains a file name. I can't really tell what `keys` is, for example, so I'm still finding it difficult to provide you with an entire 'fix'. I also don't know what the intention behind `__fix_re_pattern` is, but I think your code would work fine if you just took it out entirely.

Another problem is that for each `k` in whatever `keys` is, you overwrite the variable `matched_hashes`, so you return only the matched hashes for the last key.

Also the whole `keys` thing is kind of intriguing me.. Is it a call to some kind of globally defined function/module/class which knows about hash regexes?

Now you probably know best what your code wants, but it nevertheless seems a little complicated.. I'd advise you to keep in the back of your mind that my first answer, as it stands, also entirely meets the specification of your question.

Comment: It's working for me.. Have you changed anything? Have you changed "hashes.txt" to the appropriate filename? Is the file properly populated? Your code has gone pretty deep, but for extracting the hashes you genuinely need nothing more than my code - don't try and modify it with a `set` or anything else.

Comment: Could you at least tell me what input you're using and what it outputs, and why it's wrong?

Comment: Sorry I've been messing with it. So here's the deal, it's a function that runs through a file given as an argument. I have around 40 different regular expressions that are used as the `key` in the function above (the one I posted is the one that matches these hashes because they're SHA-1). Everything was all find and dandy until I tried to pull hashes from this CSV file. It works with text files, docx files, basically any kind of file that doesn't look like this, as long as the hashes are separated by (out of chars)

Comment: A space. The problem I'm coming across now, is that when I run this function, it won't pick up the hashes, it just pulls everything, I've tried bounding the regex, removing the beginning and ending of the regex (`^` and `$`), I tried yours (yes doing all the stuff you mentioned without changing it), but it's just simply not working for some reason. If you want to see the original and how it works look [here](https://github.com/Ekultek/Dagon/blob/master/bin/generators/__init__.py#L35). You may need to play with it a little bit to understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: Can you add to the question what your current code and output is?

Comment: Hey, I like your answer, and just to clarify, [here](https://github.com/Ekultek/Dagon/blob/master/bin/verify_hashes/verify.py#L22) is what keys makes a `list` of. It is a global regex dict, basically. I'm gonna go ahead and put yours into play, and I think I have an idea of what the problem is thank you